# Supremum, max, min, inf of $S=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\left[\frac{1}{2^n},8-\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

$S=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}\left[\frac{1}{2^n},8-\frac{1}{n}\right)$

I wrote out the first few intervals and see that this converges to the open interval $(0,8)$.  So given that I'm trying to find the union of these intervals, I believe the union of intervals is $\left[\frac{1}{2},7\right]$

If this is true, then

$\text{infS}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\text{minS}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\text{supS}=7$

$\text{maxS}=7$

Did I got about this the correct way?

Comment: You're looking for the union, not the intersection. Then check the limits.

Comment: @anonymus so it's $(0,8)$ with there being no max or min, and the inf = 0 and sup = 8?

Comment: Yes it is. It is an open interval because $1/2^n > 0$ and $8-1/n < 8$.

Comment: There is no convergence or limit process here, this is just the union of intervals, this is the reason why it is $(0,8)$. If this would be a limit process then it would be $[0,8]$.